# Double SUM query MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have 2 table
Tabel_1:

```
|idUnit  |Budget   |
|112     |1000     |
|112     |2000     |
```

Tabel_2:

```
|idUnit  | Real2   |
|112     | 500     |
|112     | 100     |
```

How to result double sum to be:

```
|idUnit  | TotalBudget | TotalReal2 |
|112     | 3000        | 600        |
```

Please help. Sorry my english poor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the tables:

**Tabel_1**

| idUnit | Budget |
| --- | --- |
| 112 | 1000 |
| 112 | 2000 |

**Tabel_2**

| idUnit | Real2 |
| --- | --- |
| 112 | 500 |
| 112 | 100 |

You can produce the following result:

| idUnit | TotalBudget | TotalReal2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 112 | 3000 | 600 |

With the following query:

```sql
SELECT t1.idUnit, SUM(Budget) AS TotalBudget, t2.TotalReal2
FROM Tabel_1 AS t1
  JOIN (SELECT idUnit, SUM(Real2) AS TotalReal2
        FROM Tabel_2 GROUP BY idUnit
  ) AS t2 ON t1.idUnit = t2.idUnit
GROUP BY t1.idUnit;
```

What we've done is group the results of joining the two tables by the `idUnit` which means that each value of `idUnit` will only show up once in the result. Then, we've used the [`SUM()` aggregate function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp) twice (once for each column we want to sum) to add the values for each `idUnit` together.

[Try it out!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca1349/12)

Comment: @D M - I think there is a small syntax error in the SELECT statement. It is missing AS   in the FROM clauses. Confirmed in your sqlfiddle. Should be: SELECT t1.idUnit, SUM(Budget) AS TotalBudget, SUM(Real2) AS TotalReal2
FROM Tabel_1 AS t1
JOIN Tabel_2 As t2 ON t1.idUnit = t2.idUnit
GROUP BY (t1.idUnit)

Comment: @LewPerren The `AS` keyword isn't strictly necessary (at least in MySQL), but I've added it for clarity. Thanks!

Comment: the query may appear but the results are inaccurate

Comment: You're correct, I missed that I was double joining. It should be fixed now, thanks.

Comment: Cool, thank u very much DM. Solved! Solved!

Comment: Hi, if given a percentage value between (totalreal / totalbudget) * 100. how to write the query

Comment: Just add another column to the outer query that calculates your percentage. If you need more details, please post another question.

Comment: How to Results for this DM sorry newbie still learn :

| idUnit | TotalBudget | TotalReal2 | Percentage |
|--------|-------------|------------|------------|
|    112 |        3000 |        600 |   20.% |
|    113 |        4000 |        200 |    5.% |

Comment: Like I said, just add another column to the outer query. You can do your calculation, use [CAST](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_cast.asp) and the [DECIMAL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp) data type to get the precision you want. Additionally, use [CONCAT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_concat.asp) to add the `%` at the end. Something like `CONCAT(CAST((t2.TotalReal2 * 100 / SUM(Budget)) AS DECIMAL(10,2)), '%')`. [Try it out!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5338c6/1)

Comment: sorry DM if you can find out where I should place the concat and cast influence. Help thanks